# installing widgets for qt

Tags: c++, qt, widget, installation

I resently found a very useful set of widgets set for qt from http://www.wysota.eu.org/wwwidgets/ and I downloaded `wwWidgets 1.0 installer for MinGW` and simply installed it. now I can see those widgets in qt creator, and I can drag and drop them.

but when compiling the project it says that those include files are not found. (ex: qwwled.h not found) but I see that file is in `C:\Qt\4.8.3\include\wwWidgets`

please if someone can help me in this issue I would be very thankful.

im using qt 4.8.3 with mingw 4.4

Comment: Is C:\Qt\4.8.3\include\wwWidgets in your include path in the project settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix your include `PATH` and add `C:\Qt\4.8.3\include\wwWidgets` to it

Add in your .pro file :

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\Qt\\4.8.3\\include\\wwWidgets"
```

But it may not be the best way, because if you share your project, the .pro must be edited.
You should use / add a environment variable

So the best solution is this one :

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$(WWWIDGETS_INCLUDE_PATH)
```

And set the environment variable `WWWIDGETS_INCLUDE_PATH` to `C:\Qt\4.8.3\include\wwWidgets`

Do not forget to add :

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += "C:\\Qt\\4.8.3\\lib\\libwwwidgets4.a"
else:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += "C:\\Qt\\4.8.3\\lib\\libwwwidgets4d.a"
```

Or add this, which is better and cleaner :

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lwwwidgets4
else:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -lwwwidgets4d
```

Comment: how should I do it. please explain

Comment: ok now I get an error `mainwindow.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6QwwLedC1EP7QWidget'`

Comment: Now your forget to add `LIBS += -lNameOfTheLib`

Comment: in `C:\Qt\4.8.3\lib` i found `libwwwidgets4.a` and `libwwwidgets4d.a` so I added `LIBS +=libwwwidgets4.a` but now I get an error `cannot find libwwwidgets4.a` what is the method to add it

Comment: Im sorrry, im new to qt. I need help

Comment: hey benjarobin you are my hero.... thanks a lot, it worked great.... thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You should add to your project file

```
CONFIG+=wwwidgets
```

---

wwWidgets installs its own *feature*  (see file `wwwidgets.prf`)
This *feature* provides information about library files and headers required for using widgets.